# Tailwind @apply in angular application .css file

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css, apply

*And I am getting yellow line under the @apply. Though the css file is working correctly and it applies the styles within the components of html, still the yellow lines are under the @apply keyword. so  each and every css file is like this. can someone please explain this?*

I want to get rid of that yellow lines. It is like a mess

[Code I tried so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBWB1.png)

Comment: please post the code what you've tried so far, and what IDE are you working on!

Comment: i added the images of my code. can you check it and tell me where I got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add this property to .vscode/settings.json in your workspace

```
"css.customData": ["./tailwind.json"],
```

Add a tailwind.json file at root

```json
{
  "version": 1.1,
  "atDirectives": [
    {
      "name": "@tailwind",
      "description": "Use the @tailwind directive to insert Tailwind's `base`, `components`, `utilities`, and `screens` styles into your CSS."
    },
    {
      "name": "@apply",
      "description": "Use @apply to inline any existing utility classes into your own custom CSS."
    }
  ]
}
```